# ios UIImage reveal over another UIImage animation

Tags: ios

i have two images of exact size . Imagine two images of a room, one with sunlight and another with artificial light.I have to place them one over other and add a slider,so that when slider is moved the below image will show according to slider value. Ex - If slider is on half position then user will be able to show half of image with sunlight and half with artificial light giving it a curtain effect.

i have searched a lot and failed to find any clue as how to do this. Please suggest any tutorial to do this kind of animation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the sliders minimum value to 0 and it's maximum value to 1

```
[mySlider setMinimumValue:0.0f];
[mySlider setMaximumValue:1.0f];
```

When the slider is changed by the user get the current value

```
float sliderProgress = mySlider.value;
```

adjust the alpha values of both images dependant upon the value.

```
[imageSunlight setAlpha:sliderProgress];
```

and the other image's alpha would be

```
[imageArtificialLight setAlpha:(1.0f - sliderProgress)];
```

Comment: Rishi, @Damo is right. You don't need to do anything special for animation unless you want the effect to be slower than the UI.

Comment: Note that you don't need to change the alpha of both images if the image on top doesn't have transparency and depending on what effect you want.

Comment: thanks friend but i did not want this.Images are exactly placed over each other you cannot see background image until to slide the upper image and according  to slider value the behind image portion will be visible.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a good basis to solve your problem - have you tried it yet?

Comment: yes i already know this i have used alpha values previously.Alpha value will apply on whole image. i do not want this.Imagine a shuffle door if you slide it 20% u can see the back of only 20% same as i want if slider is 20% back image will be seen only 20% and rest 80% will be foreground image.Sample App to look into is "BMW ipad" app.

Comment: ahhhhh - I suspect you are not going to find a tutorial to tell you exactly how to do it as it seems a bit niche. If you are unlucky you might have to apply a mask to the image to get the effect. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Damo for your comments.